# Create multidimensional torch tensor time series

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, time-series, tensor

I want to create a torch tensor sequence out of a multi-dimensional numpy array. I've achieved it with 1-d arrays, but can't find the proper way with more dimensions...

This is a 1-d vector example:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

n = np.arange(10)
t = torch.tensor([n[i: i + 3] for i in range(7)])
```

Being the output:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Let's say that instead of a 1-d vector I have a 2-d one.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

n = np.array([np.arange(10), np.arange(10, 20)])
t = torch.tensor([n[..., i: i + 3] for i in range(7)]).view(2, -1, 3)
```

The output is:

```
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [10, 11, 12],
         [ 1,  2,  3],
         [11, 12, 13],
         [ 2,  3,  4],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [ 3,  4,  5]],

        [[13, 14, 15],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [14, 15, 16],
         [ 5,  6,  7],
         [15, 16, 17],
         [ 6,  7,  8],
         [16, 17, 18]]])
```

And what I’m looking for is:

```
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 2,  3,  4],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 5,  6,  7],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

         [[10, 11, 12],  
         [11, 12, 13],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [13, 14, 15],
         [14, 15, 16],
         [15, 16, 17],     
         [16, 17, 18]]])
```

As you can see the rows are alternated... Is there any way of achieving it?

P.D: In case there is a more elegant solution to solve the problem, I will be very grateful too! I've tried with methods as `torch.repeat_interleave` but couldn't achieve anything...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what formula you want to implement, but looks like it should be `t[i, j, k] = i*10 + j + k`. This formula is nothing but the outer sum of the three index ranges. The most straightforward way to obtain it is

```
t = torch.tensor(np.add.outer(np.arange(2)*10, np.add.outer(np.arange(7), np.arange(3))))
```

Which gives

```
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 2,  3,  4],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 5,  6,  7],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        [[10, 11, 12],
         [11, 12, 13],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [13, 14, 15],
         [14, 15, 16],
         [15, 16, 17],
         [16, 17, 18]]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Comment: Sorry, I added an example output of what I’m looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It is still not 100% clear what you need, but I changed the answer to match the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by concatenating the sub-tensors along the appropriate axis:

```py
n = np.array([np.arange(10), np.arange(10, 20)])
t = torch.tensor([n[..., i: i + 3] for i in range(7)])

t = torch.cat([_ for _ in t.unsqueeze(-2)], dim=1)
```